# Creating Layered PDF using Javascript in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I've read through the documentation of [PDFMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake), and [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/), and [WPS: PostScript for the Web](http://logand.com/sw/wps/) but haven't been able to find any reference to anything other than background layers, from looking at various documentation, it sounds like [Optional Content Groups](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/pdfl_sdk/9/PDFL_SDK9_HTMLHelp/API_References/Acrobat_API_Reference/PD_Layer/PDOCG.html) are what I need, but how to handle them using Javascript, I've no idea (I've found little about OCG and layers generally, which isn't sounding promising)!

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Having tried a few libraries, PDFKit appears to be the best bet, it doesn't discuss layers, but each object you add does exist as a layer, and placing items on top of each other will layer them.

Comment: I tried to use `pdfkit` library but generated pdf file doesn't have any layers.